# input date and time in play framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i am trying to input date and time in play framework.
in my model i have this

```
import java.util.*;
@Required
public Date date;
```

and then in my views i am using bootstrap-datetimepicker

```
 <div class="well">

     @helper.form(action = routes.EventController.addEvent()) {
     @helper.inputText(userForm("eventname"))
     @helper.inputText(userForm("username"))

     @helper.inputText(
    userForm("date"),
    '_label -> "label",
    'type -> "text"
     )

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}

<script>$('#date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss'
});
</script>
    </div>
```

now when i return the saved event then the date is correct but the time information is not saved basically it shows 00:00:00 please tell me what should i do..i have tried many things but nothing seems to work..
PS-when i analyse the demo post request it shows me this as form data-
eventname=&username=v&date=2014-06-25+22%3A50%3A27
i think the format for the date is right or so you think i should change it?

Edit-code for addevent controller

```
public static Result addEvent()
    {   //just sample code.use id stored in session
            Club club = Club.find.byId(1L);
        Form<Event> submittedform = userForm.bindFromRequest();
        if(submittedform.hasErrors())
        {   
            return ok(views.html.addevent.render(submittedform));

        }
        else{
         Event event = submittedform.get();

         event.club=club;
         event.save();
         System.out.println(event.event_id);
         return ok(views.html.created.render(event));
        }
    }
```

Comment: you might want to add the code for the form

Comment: sorry i didn't understand which form? i have added code of my views template.

Comment: i even tried using @Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm") in model and then in format in javascript as 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii' but it return invalid value as error

Comment: I mean the code for EventController.addEvent()

Comment: okay i dont know how and why but i just attached a debugger then inspected the values and after i resumed..it started working..i didn't change anything..maybe it is some bug..i had previously done clean and compile but it hadn't solved my problem..i am still confused but it working now